# A simple solution to the PWM controlled DC fan?

Tags: pwm, fan

I am trying to temperature control a set of 12V DC fans (2 wires) of mine.

I went down the pwm microcontroller output + mofset rabbit hole (increases the noise / can damage the fans), read about RC filters (not energy efficient, dont reach full speed), and now LC filters.

But this is way beyond my understanding, and I don't feel comfortable building a complex electronic device using capacitors and such for production use (24/7) inside a non ventilated cabinet.

**Question**:

Instead of tinkering, would the following setup achieve desired results, and be safe?

- Drive the fan speed using a [DC Led Dimmer](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005005457743652.html).
- Smooth the electrical output with a [4A LC Filter](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005005557434358.html)
- Use home assistant, a raspberry pi and a temperature sensor to control the dimmer

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think anyone can say if it is safe to self-import a mains-connected product from places like Aliexpress, nor if it will work with an LC filter with a fan as load, which looks highly different than the intended load such as LEDs.

Comment: I’d like to know more about how your original micro+mosfet solution didn’t work out. I’d also like to know if these are true dc brushed motors or if they’re brushless fan motors like a PC cooling fan.

Comment: @Bryan I haven't tried it out really, but read around that it may cause noise and damage the fans. Not that the fans are so valuable but reducing noise is the main reason why I want to temperature control them. I have made a simulation of the circuit if you're interested: https://www.tinkercad.com/things/8Y2Vev68Unr-tempcontrolledfan?sharecode=DAu4BQYHYI92WbH-fNiluYfH13u9GRsABFitQTrCbDM
Also implemented the RC smoothed one: https://www.tinkercad.com/things/axN0RranlVx-smoothedtempcontrolledfan?sharecode=biAHMCzi4zXrDM2J31RXheve-na96pT8a0r5A1nEYDI

Answer (score 2):

No, and no. The DC dimmer assumes a non-reactive load (LED) so it won't behave well with a fan. And, it has a max voltage of 24V which exceeds the fan spec input voltage (12V), and probably frying it in the process.

PWM control of brushless DC fans is never perfect, as the fan may not behave well due to the chopping of the power supply to the fan control IC. Some fans can deal with it because they have some internal filtering for that control circuit, others will freak out depending on the PWM frequency. Most people use low-ish chop (30Hz or so) and get reasonable results.

Filtering the PWM yields a DC control. This has limited range, depending again on the fan control IC and its internal power supply. Figure the fan will stop running at about 6V or so.

These two issues are why 4-wire fans were developed: the PWM control only affects the coils, but not the fan IC itself, so a wide control range is possible.

tl, dr: If you have a choice, adopting a 4-wire fan will make your life easier.

Comment: thanks for replying! it's really not ideal as I already bought and mounted 12 of these fans but if at least I could find the same form factor maybe I could just replace the existing with some 4 wires ones and I'm done